# asp.net mvc hidden for creating value="null" on a datetime

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Any ideas on why this would be happening?
I have a model with DateTime property called Date which is just set to smalldatetime min value 1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM

For test purposes in the view I am directly putting it into markup and then also doing a HiddenFor

[image: value is null]

The direct markup shows the value just fine

[image: value is null]

But the rendered hidden input is setting the value to be "null"

[image: value is null]

The direct markup proves the value is there, but why is HiddenFor not acknowledging it and just putting "null"

Comment: Is that in a form tag ?

Comment: Yes, I didn't include it in the screen shot but it is in a form by way of Html.BeginForm

Comment: Can you share your model code?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set datetime to null in SQL server so thats the default

Comment: Um, SQL Server allows nullable datetime fields. I dunno where you heard otherwise.